Why is diagram b the simplified diagram for this multi stage amplifier?
The following is from the book RF MICROELECTRONICS Page 56.
Determine the noise figure of the circuit shown in Fig. 2.53(a). Neglect transistor capacitances, flicker noise, channel-length modulation, and body effect.

The author hasn't explained how he derives this figure (b) and what \$R_{out1}\$ is.

In my opinion, according to figure above with test voltage.
$$R_{out1} = \frac{V_T} {I_T} = r_{o1}$$
This schematic can be further simplified to this figure below, where you can see \$R_{D1}\$ and \$r_{o1}\$ are in parallel.


Neglecting channel-length modulation means $r_o \to \infty$.

@a360pilot I see. If we can't neglect channel length modulation, Is $R_{D1}$ in parallel with $r_{o1}$ in this simplified diagram?

yes, that is correct.

@a360pilot - Hi, Thanks for helping. However we really want to avoid having questions answered in comments, since (a) answering is not an allowed use of comments & (b) answering comments can actually harm the site. || If an answer has been accidentally discovered or confirmed during (allowed) clarification in comments, please consider writing an actual answer, which the OP can accept. Or, if you don't want to do that, invite the OP to write a self-answer. TY

@kile in accordance to what the moderator said, please attempt a self-answer if my guidance helped you resolve your issue. Thank you.
